# Install Both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python, python-2.7, python3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [need to have 2 versions of python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196071/need-to-have-2-versions-of-python)

I have projects that require different resources from the two different versions of Python. My question is can I have both versions of python installed and if I can how do I switch between the two in different projects. Any help afforded is appreciated!

mojo706

Comment: I'm sorry for putting in a duplicate question I found something close to this [Need 2 versions of Python](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196071/need-to-have-2-versions-of-python?rq=1) If you had viewed this please use the above link. mojo706